# static map not intialized correctly?

Tags: c++, constructor, clang, objective-c++, static-initialization

I'm using some c++ code in a static library in a macOS App. The c++ code contains the following:

```
static map<char*, char*> aMap1;


__attribute__((constructor))
static void initialize() {
{
    static map<char*, char*> aMap2;
    printf("map1: %d, map2: %d\n", aMap1.begin() == aMap1.end(), aMap2.begin() == aMap2.end()); // prints map1: 0, map2: 1
}
```

`aMap1.begin()` does not equal `aMap1.end()`, even though `aMap1.size()` is 0. `sizeof(aMap1)` is 24, and the 24 bytes at `&aMap1` are 0. Calling `aMap1.clear()` before the for loop makes `begin()` equal `end()`.

`aMap2.begin()` does equal `aMap2.end()`, and the bytes are non-zero.

I was under the impression that aMap1 was initialized automatically, but this appears to be incorrect?

Comment: What's up with the `free()` call? Do you `malloc()` somewhere, and if so, why?

Comment: This isn't all the code of course, and later in the application elements are added to the map which are allocated with `malloc`. I've left it here to demonstrate that it crashes because it is entering the for loop with an empty list

Comment: What we really need is a [mcve].

Comment: It probably should not be all zeroes. So your actual problem is that the constructor is not being called? Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579668/linking-to-static-c-library-on-mac-os-x-global-object-constructor-from-librar

Comment: How come there is no `free(i->second);` or `delete i->second;`?  (Or does something else own the SomeClass objects?)

Comment: I've removed the excess code as it is not relevant. I can't reproduce in a standalone example.

Comment: @Nick For starters  this declaration of std::map map<char*, char*> aMap1; does not make a sense. How are you going to compare pointers?

Comment: @Nick `I can't reproduce in a standalone example` Then the problem is probably  in the code that you removed. Remove only the parts that don't cause the example to reproduce.

Comment: The changed code is not reproducing the bug for me.  I suspect there is a bug elsewhere is the code that is causing undefined behavior, which may be exhibiting by stomping on the `aMap` object.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/M3xdbb) ([catch2 version](https://godbolt.org/z/rzMc6f)). Please provide [mcve].

Comment: someFunc was being called from an `__attribute__((constructor))` function, so it was being called before the aMap1 initializer. I've edited the question to demonstrate.

Comment: You cannot use an object before it is constructed.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware – I just hadn't realised this was the cause.

Comment: post answer at answers and not within question.

Comment: I was unable to at the time as the question had been closed. It’s reopened now, so I’ve answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`someFunc` was being called from an `__attribute__((constructor))` function, so it was being called before the `aMap1` initializer. To resolve the issue I moved the code to a dispatch block. The function could also be called from `main` instead of being marked as a constructor.

```
static map<char*, char*> aMap1;

__attribute__((constructor))
static void initialize() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        static map<char*, char*> aMap2;
        printf("map1: %d, map2: %d\n", aMap1.begin() == aMap1.end(), aMap2.begin() == aMap2.end()); // prints map1: 1, map2: 1
    });
}
```

Comment: The question as edited is reproducible. I've edited my answer to provide a solution.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the `__attribute__((constructor))` function is an implementation-defined compiler extension, so the C++ standard is no help in understanding its behaviour.

[Clang's attribute reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html) doesn't actually mention it, so we have to go back to [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), as clang implements this attribute in order to be compatible with the GNU dialects of C/C++/Objective-C.

> The `constructor` attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters main ().

No specified relative order vs C++ static initialisers so far. However, it soon becomes clear that the constructor function runs *before* static C++ initialisers:

> You may provide an optional integer priority […] A constructor with a smaller priority number runs before a constructor with a larger priority number; […] The priorities for constructor and destructor functions are the same as those specified for namespace-scope C++ objects (see C++ Attributes).

If you then look at the [documentation for the `init_priority()` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html#C_002b_002b-Attributes) you find its `priority` argument to be:

> […] a constant integral expression currently bounded between 101 and 65535 inclusive. Lower numbers indicate a higher priority.

In other words, you can put multiple `__attribute__((constructor))` functions in a specific relative order with priority 0…100, and statically initialised C++ objects in an order 101…65535 to override the default behaviour of objects being initialised in the order of definition in a compilation unit, and order being unspecified across compilation units. But this also means that the last constructor function always runs before the first C++ static initialiser.

This explains the behaviour you are seeing. Your constructor function runs before `aMap1`'s constructor. `aMap1` *is* automatically constructed, but not until after the constructor function has completed.

For ways to solve this problem, see [the relevant entry in the C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use-members).